# Graphing a Function with the Given Properties

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, graphing-functions

[image]

[image]
I’m having trouble drawing a function that has these properties. In particular, the continuity and differentiable parts. The picture provided takes cover of (a) and (d). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, the only parts that you have right are a and d.  Look up what a jump discontinuity is maybe.  Have a sharp turn at $\pm 2$ so that it is not differentiable.  For the last part, just have two horizontal asymptotes at $\pm 1$ such that the function is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a jump discontinuity at $x = a$ exists whenever $\lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = L^-$ and $\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = L^+$ both exist and yet $L^- \neq L^+.$ Consequently, one can visualize these (quite literally) as a jump in the function from one point on the left-hand side to a distinct point on the right-hand side. Be careful when writing the jump discontinuities to choose your values so that you do not violate the (odd) symmetry of $f(x).$

Recall that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = a$ whenever the limit $$f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a)} h = \lim_{h \to 0} Q_a(h)$$ exists. Consequently, if you wish for $f(x)$ to *not* be differentiable at $x = a,$ you can force a jump discontinuity in $Q_a(h)$ as $h$ tends to $0.$ Particularly, you may take $\lim_{h \to 0^-} Q_a(h) \neq \lim_{h \to 0^+} Q_a(h).$ Graphically, this amounts to forcing a cusp or a corner in your function at $x = a$ since the function $Q_a(h)$ gives the slope of the secant line of $f(x)$ over the interval $[a, a + h].$ Once again, be careful not to mess up the symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

For example,
[image]

\begin{align} 
f(x)&=
\begin{cases}
-\sin(\tfrac\pi2\,x),\quad & x\in [0,1)
,\\
3-x,\quad &x\in [1,2)
,\\
(-2x+4)\exp(-x+3)+1,\quad &x\in [2,\infty)
,\\
-f(-x),\quad & x<0
.
\end{cases}
\end{align}